# What does a forward slash before a variable name do in Xcode + Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In an Xcode project, using the Swift language, I've seen some lines of code use a forward slash just before a variable. For example:

```
func printSomething(something: String) {
    print(/something)
}

printSomething(something: "This is something")
```

Which gives the same output as if it didn't have the forward slash:

```
This is something
```

However, when trying to compile this outside of Xcode, it fails with

```
error: '/' is not a prefix unary operator
```

So I guess it is something particular to Xcode or iOS.

What does this forward slash do? I can't tell the difference and can't seem to find any resources on this.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I get the error that `/` is not a prefix unary operator as well.

Comment: Cannot reproduce either. Is that your exact, copy-pasted code? What happens if you compile that code in a new, fresh Xcode project?

Comment: control-command-click on the slash. Somebody added their own operator to the project.

Comment: @Jessy Yup, after doing what you suggested I found that the original author added his/her own operator with `prefix operator /`. Didn't know Swift allowed adding one's own operators. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're not misremembering, and it was actually a `\` you were seeing - in that case you would be referring to [keypaths](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-are-keypaths). These are a way of storing uninvoked references to properties, they refer to a property itself rather than to that property’s value.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently looking at the code. Nonetheless, Jessy's comment pointed me to the right direction. It was a custom operator by the original author. Woops.